# SQL-Using unique constraints to remove duplicate entries from being entered in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql statement and I am trying to add a unique constraint that prevents an duplicate entry from being entered twice in the table. Can anyone help me out with my code if I am writing it correctly?

```
 CREATE TABLE GroupMembership
 (GroupID INT REFERENCES dbo.Groups (GroupID),
 IndividualID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Individuals (IndividualID) PRIMARY KEY(GroupID,      IndividualID), 
 CONSTRAINT AK_IndividualID UNIQUE IndividualID);
```

I tried to test it via SQL server but it is giving me an error.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: The problem is in your syntax, Check Mureinik's Ans it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a couple of things:

1. A comma after the `IndividualId` column specification (as the primary key does not relate to it - it's a multiple-column constraint)
2. Brackets around the `IndividualId` column in the unique constraint specification.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE GroupMembership
(GroupID INT REFERENCES dbo.Groups (GroupID),
 IndividualID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES dbo.Individuals (IndividualID),
 PRIMARY KEY(GroupID,      IndividualID), 
 CONSTRAINT AK_IndividualID UNIQUE (IndividualID)
);
```